# Problem in inserting primary Key in table

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have 2 tables, corporate (Used to store Login info), and assignment (used to store assignment details).

**Columns in Corporate table**: id(Primary key autoincrement), uname,password.
Id is not taken from the user.

**Columns in assignment table**: assignment_topic,assignment_content, total_marks, id (Foreign key), id_assignment(primary key autoincrement).

**Information flow:**
1. Login user --> Apart from checking if valid user or not, initialize the id(1000) and return it (searchId() method).
2. UI input details of the assignment from the user --> BackgroundTask ---> insertAssignment method.

**Issue**: I am not able to insert id(FOREIGN KEY) in assignment table by retrieving the id(primary key) from the corporate table. The concerned column is showing as null.

**Tried the following:**

1. As you can see in the DatabaseHelper class, I tried the foreign key but it did not work and hence removed it.
2. Apart from the above I tried getting the id through getters and setters, was able to do it up to an extent but don't know where the data is breaking.

As I am new to Android it would be great if you guys could help me resolve this issue.

Please let me know if you require any further information from my end.

Below is the necessary code.

Insert_assignment class:

```
public void SubmitData(View view) {

    String topic_assign = topic.getText().toString();
    String topic_content_assign = topic_content.getText().toString();
    String total_marks = t_marks.getText().toString();
    String id = loginInfo.getId();

    Log.e("assignment_id:",id);

    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute("add_assignment", topic_assign, topic_content_assign, total_marks,id);
}
```

BackgroundTask class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Teacher_Assignment, String> {

    private static final String TAG = " Background task";

    LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo();

    Activity activity;
    ListView listView;

    AssignmentAdapter assignmentAdapter;
    Teacher_Assignment teacher_assignment = new Teacher_Assignment();

    private Context context;


    BackgroundTask(Context context)
    {
        this.context =  context;
        activity = (Activity)context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String method = params[0];
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        if(method.equals("add_assignment")) {
            String topic_assignment = params[1];
            String topic_content = params[2];
            String total_marks = params[3];
            String id = params[4];


            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            databaseHelper.insertAssignment(db,topic_assignment,topic_content,total_marks, id);
            Log.d(TAG,"inserted successfully");

        } else if(method.equals("get_info")) {

            listView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.list_assignment);

            //DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getInformation(db);


            assignmentAdapter = new AssignmentAdapter(context, R.layout.activity_assignment_page_recycle_view);

            String assignment_content;
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){

                assignment_content = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(teacher_assignment.Assignment_content));
                Teacher_Assignment teacher_assignment = new Teacher_Assignment(assignment_content);
                publishProgress(teacher_assignment);
            }

            return "get_info";
        }


        return "One row inserted";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.equals("get_info")) {
            listView.setAdapter(assignmentAdapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(Assignment_Page... values) {
        assignmentAdapter.add(values[2]);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper class:

```
package com.example.education;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.util.Log;

class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo();

    Teacher_Assignment assign1 = new Teacher_Assignment();

    //Login table
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 41;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userInfo.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "corporate";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "uname";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";

    private static final String TABLE_ASSIGNMENT = "assignment";
    //private static final String COLUMN_ID_ASSIGNMENT = "user_id";
    private static final String ASSIGNMENT_TOPIC = "assignment_topic";
    //private static final String COLUMN_NAME = COLUMN_UNAME;
    private static final String ASSIGNMENT_CONTENT = "assignment_content";
    private static final String ASSIGNMENT_TOTAL_MARKS = "total_marks";
    private static final String ID_COLUMN_ASSIGNMENT = "id_assignment";


    private static final String TABLE_STUDENT_SELECTION = "student_selection";
    private static final String COLUMN_STUDENT_ID = "student_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_CLASS_SEC = "class_sec";
    private static final String COLUMN_STUDENT_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COLUMN_TOTAL_MARKS = "total_marks";
    private static final String COLUMN_STUDENT_MARKS = "student_score";



    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_UNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL " + ")";


    private static final String CREATE_ASSIGNMENT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ASSIGNMENT + "("
            + ASSIGNMENT_TOPIC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ASSIGNMENT_CONTENT  + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ASSIGNMENT_TOTAL_MARKS + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ID_COLUMN_ASSIGNMENT + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_ID + " TEXT " + ")";


    //+ " FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME + " (id) "

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void insertData() {

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();

        content.put(COLUMN_ID,1000);
        content.put(COLUMN_UNAME, "akhil");
        content.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,"admin");



        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, content);

        db.close();
    }

    public String insertAssignment(SQLiteDatabase db,String topic, String assignment_content, String total_marks, String id) {

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content1 = new ContentValues();

        //id = searchId(COLUMN_UNAME);

        content1.put(ASSIGNMENT_TOPIC, topic);
        content1.put(ASSIGNMENT_CONTENT,assignment_content);
        content1.put(ASSIGNMENT_TOTAL_MARKS,total_marks);
        content1.put(COLUMN_ID, loginInfo.getId());
        db.insert(TABLE_ASSIGNMENT, null, content1);
        db.close();

        return topic;
    }
```

Database screenshot:

[image]

Comment: when you are taking id as a parameter in your method, then why are you fetching value from loginInfo ?

Comment: I am taking it as a parameter because in my background task I am storing the data through logininfo.getid() ...can you please tell me an alternate way in which i can get the id

Comment: Shouldn't you just be using **`content1.put(COLUMN_ID, id);`** rather than `content1.put(COLUMN_ID, loginInfo.getId());`?

Comment: Hi mike ..I tried using content1.put(COLUMN_ID, id); but still getting null

Answer (score 0):

The id value come from loginInfo instance which is initialized in BackgroundTask:

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

LoginInfo loginInfo = new LoginInfo();
```

If the id is obtained with `//id = searchId(COLUMN_UNAME);` check on the searchId method .

Comment: when not commenting id = searchId(COLUMN_UNAME); , as you can see in the database screenshot the value comes to not found instead of null

Comment: The searchId() method is returning "not found" .

Comment: ok so it is taking the initial value of the id..can u please help me fix this...does it have to do with the columnindex.

Comment: Share us the searchId() method.

Comment: Please find below the searchID() method as well as the searchLogin method()

Comment: public String searchId(String uname) {
 db = this.getReadableDatabase();  String query = " SELECT id,uname FROM corporate ";Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
String id, b;
id = "not found";
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            }
            do {
                 b = cursor.getString(1);     Log.e("name:", b);
                if (b.equals(uname)) {
                    id = cursor.getString(0);
                    Log.e("Id sent:", id);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
            return id;
        }

Comment: public String searchLogin(String uname) {
 db = this.getReadableDatabase();
 String query = " SELECT uname,password FROM corporate ";
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
 String a, b;
 b = "not found";
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        }
        do {

            a = cursor.getString(0);
            Log.e("username:", a);

            if (a.equals(uname)) {
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                Log.e("password:", b);
                break;
            }
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
        return b;
    }

Comment: The code call searchId(COLUMN_UNAME) which is "uname". The database has  a record in **corporate** table in which the column value is uname?

Maybe on the call of searchId you should pass the a value or expression with the username.

Comment: Hi amamede,can you please elaborate a little more on your response

Comment: as you can see from the code above this particular line has been commented out

Comment: id = searchId(COLUMN_UNAME);

Comment: In searchId it is returning the *id* variable. This variable is set to "not found":  `id = "not found"`. The same with searchLogin but with *b* variable.

Comment: yes but in searchLogin the correct value is being returned:09-20 18:12:11.866 30930-30930/com.example.education E/username:: akhil
09-20 18:12:11.866 30930-30930/com.example.education E/password:: admin
09-20 18:12:11.869 30930-30930/com.example.education E/name:: akhil
09-20 18:12:11.869 30930-30930/com.example.education E/Id sent:: 1000

Comment: wheras when checking searchId as you can see from the code below :public         String id, b;
 id = "not found";
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
 }
 do {
b = cursor.getString(1);
 Log.e("name:", b);
 if (b.equals(uname)) {
 id = cursor.getString(0);
  Log.e("Id sent:", id);
  break;
   }
     }
   while (cursor.moveToNext());
  return id;
  }
09-20 18:12:11.869 30930-30930/com.example.education E/name:: akhil
09-20 18:12:11.869 30930-30930/com.example.education E/Id sent:: 1000

Comment: Dont know y it is still returning as not found even when the logs clearly show that id is being passed

Comment: I suggest to print the uname variable along with b variable, and also log the expression `b.equals(uname)`

Comment: 09-21 16:16:37.937 551-551/com.example.education E/name:: akhil
09-21 16:16:37.937 551-551/com.example.education E/Id sent:: 1000

Comment: Above logs are for the below code:
public String searchId(String uname) {
db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String query = " SELECT id,uname FROM corporate ";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
String id, b;
id = "not found";
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
 }
do {
b = cursor.getString(1);
Log.e("name:", b);
 if (b.equals(uname)) {
                    id = cursor.getString(0);
                    Log.e("Id sent:", id);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
            return id;
        }

Comment: Log the uname variable. Something like `Log.e("uname", uname);` in the line after `Log.e("name:", b);`

Comment: Hi amamede, please find below the logs:

09-22 14:23:25.083 2670-2911/com.example.education E/name:: akhil
09-22 14:23:25.084 2670-2911/com.example.education E/uname :: uname

Comment: Hello, from your logs the **uname** variable has the value `uname` . You're search an user with username `uname` instead of `akhil`

From your code the constant COLUMN_UNAME has `uname` string value, and it is used in commented code  `//id = searchId(COLUMN_UNAME);` . You should pass an argument with a real username, registered in `corporate` table .

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by passing the data from one activity to another and then calling the SearchId function